# Change of flavour in strong interactions?

Tags: feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, matter, strong-force

Sorry if this question has been asked already but after researching I have found that quark flavour is not changed in the strong interaction. This confused me because how can a down and anti down quark both change flavour to a strange and antistrange quark in diagram below?

[image: Proton-pion]

Answer (score 2):

Only the weak interactions can change the *net* flavour.

The process $d + \bar{d} \to g$ and $g \to s + \bar{s}$ does not change the net number of down quarks or the net number of strange quarks, where the net number is the number of quarks minus the number of antiquarks.